# Options for Scala DataStreamReader Class 'format' Value Member

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm new to Scala and Spark but I'm working on "POCing" Structured Streaming and one of the available API class is DataStreamReader accessed by a sample code below:

```
val spark: SparkSession = ...
// Read text from socket
val socketDF = spark
  .readStream
  .format("socket")
  .option("host", "localhost")
  .option("port", 9999)
  .load()
```

**.readStream** returns DataStreamReader class and is furthered accessed with **.format** member and you can specify other parameters besides "socket" i.e. "text" or "parquet".  Information on these parameters are vague and not fully listed on [Spark's Structured Steaming Programming Guide](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html).  and I've tried looking at the [DataStreamReader](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.DataStreamReader) API but it doesn't tell you any of the available parameters.  Where can I find these information?

Answer (score 1):

You have given all fields. There is no mistake there. You can refer this [blog](https://blog.knoldus.com/2017/06/18/spark-structured-streaming-a-simple-definition/)

First run the netcat server on different tab `nc -lk 9999`
In your spark shell,

```
    import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
    import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

    val spark = SparkSession
      .builder
      .appName("StructuredNetworkWordCount")
      .getOrCreate()

    import spark.implicits._

    val lines = spark.readStream
      .format("socket")
      .option("host", "localhost")
      .option("port", 9999)
      .load()

    val words = lines.as[String].flatMap(_.split(" "))

    val wordCounts = words.groupBy("value").count()

val query = wordCounts.writeStream
  .outputMode("complete")
  .format("console")
  .start()

query.awaitTermination()
```

When you type anything on netcat server, it will be consumed by spark..

```
nc -lk 9999
hi
this is first example of spark structtyred
streaing

-------------------------------------------
Batch: 0
-------------------------------------------
+-----+-----+                                                                   
|value|count|
+-----+-----+
|   hi|    1|
+-----+-----+

-------------------------------------------
Batch: 1
-------------------------------------------
+-----------+-----+                                                             
|      value|count|
+-----------+-----+
|    example|    1|
|         is|    1|
|      spark|    1|
|         of|    1|
|         hi|    1|
|       this|    1|
|      first|    1|
|structtyred|    1|
+-----------+-----+

-------------------------------------------
Batch: 2
-------------------------------------------
+-----------+-----+                                                             
|      value|count|
+-----------+-----+
|   streaing|    1|
|    example|    1|
|         is|    1|
|      spark|    1|
|         of|    1|
|         hi|    1|
|       this|    1|
|      first|    1|
|structtyred|    1|
+-----------+-----+
```

Comment: I think my question was poorly stated.  Basically I wanted to know what available options are for value members such as .option or .format.  For example .format has "socket" "text", or "parquet".  However the API document doesn't state all available option. Basically where can I find these?

Answer (score 0):

does the spark structured streaming (2.2.1) support MySQL as the data source. Spark streaming supports custom receivers . Does the spark structured streaming has similar facility?

Comment: Please create another a separate topic for your question.